# jersey @NotNull doesn't check on input

Tags: jersey

I have a jersey REST service, and I use @NotNull to check on the @pathparam, but it seems not working.I've include jersey-bean-validation in pom.xml

my code is here:

```
@Path("/resource")
public class MyResource extends AbstractResource {
    @POST
    @Path("/report")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ResponseClass(ReportAcknowledgement.class)
    public Response getGrowthResults(MyRequest request,
                                     @Context HttpHeaders headers) throws Exception {

        String organizationId = request.getOrganization(); <-- null here
        ..
        validateOrganization(organizationId);


public abstract class AbstractResource {
    ..
    protected void validateOrganization(@NotNull(message = "{org.string.null}")  @Valid String organizationId) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I imagine the validation annotation need to go on the concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using the [`jersey-bean-validation`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-bean-validation/2.22.2) dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>
```

According to the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html), having the above mentioned dependency on the classpath will activate the Bean Validation feature on Jersey.

Answer (score 0):

The question is super-old, so you have probably already found an answer...

But you are missing the @Valid annotation on the parameter.

Try this

```
@POST
@Path("/report")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ResponseClass(ReportAcknowledgement.class)
public Response getGrowthResults(@javax.validation.Valid MyRequest request,
                                     @Context HttpHeaders headers) throws Exception {
        String organizationId = request.getOrganization(); <-- null here
        ..
        validateOrganization(organizationId);
}
```